# oracle procedure create and run ora-00900 error

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

l made oracle procedure in dbeaver like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test
IS
    I_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(100) := 'test';
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(I_MESSAGE);
END;
```

then l run `exec p_test;`
procedure was not working with `ORA-00900` error
l don't understand why not working..

Comment: Where are you executing your PL/SQL code?

Comment: cant executing with exec p_test; ?

Comment: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/749 ...using statement begin .. end. It's working code

Comment: it's works!!! really really thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

`exec p_test` is an `sql*plus` command. 
If you are using an IDE you should try:

```
BEGIN
    p_test;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
BEGIN
    p_test;
END;
```

It's work.

EXEC is SQL*Plus command, it is no a part of PL/SQL.